# Windows System Call to OPEN/CLOSE other exe file

Tags: c++, c, winapi, system-calls

```
system("C:\\server.exe ine >> request.xml");
```

This program takes ine as parameter and writes output to file request.xml. The program successfully writes output to file, but it does not close the file. I tried

```
exit(0)
```

but it not execute after system(...)

It looks like the program is hanged, and i have to close it manually.

How can i close the program pragmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `system`. It seems like the process you call (`C:\server.exe`) is not exiting after you launch it. `system` will just hang until the process exits.

Instead, consider using `CreateProcess` and `TerminateProcess` to control the lifecycle of your program more carefully. In that case, you will have to specify the output file manually via STARTUPINFO.hStdOutput, or call `cmd.exe` with the desired command line.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `C:\server.exe`. It isn't exiting properly.